# I've installed a Public Key, but my login doesn't ask for the passphrase

Tags: ssh

I'm following this tutorial [SSH Tutorial for Linux](http://support.suso.com/supki/SSH_Tutorial_for_Linux)

I've manually transfered the public key to the remote server and I ran these commands also because it wasn't asking me for my passphrase.

`chmod 700 ~/.ssh` &
`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

But still it doesn't ask me for my passphrase. I tried the newer automatic way to install the public key `ssh-copy-id -p 2222 yourusername@your.website.com` and got this error message:

> Bad port 'umask 077; test -d ~/.ssh || mkdir ~/.ssh ; cat >>
>   ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && (test -x /sbin/restorecon &&
>   /sbin/restorecon ~/.ssh ~/.ssh/authorized_keys >/dev/null 2>&1 ||
>   true)'

**Is this error because I've already transferred it manually?**

I ran `ssh` login with `-v` these are the mentions of `public key`:**

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/localusername/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/localusername/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/localusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
```

**I'll note this is prior to logging in.**

Comment: have you tried  `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@remotehost -p2222`  Also `scp` for example uses `P` capital letter to specify a remote port.

Answer (score 0):

I think those errors are because the `ssh-copy-id` script doesn't appear to be able to handle the `-p` switch for a different port.

This is the line out of my version of that script:

```
{ eval "$GET_ID" ; } | ssh $1 "umask 077; test -d .ssh || mkdir .ssh ; cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys; test -x /sbin/restorecon && /sbi
n/restorecon .ssh .ssh/authorized_keys" || exit 1
```

Notice there isn't any arguments being passed into `ssh-copy-id` that would incorporate the `-p 2222` argument. At least not as the 1st argument to `ssh-copy-id` as you're attempting to use it. The usage is shown as this:

```
$ ssh-copy-id -h
Usage: /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id [-i [identity_file]] [user@]machine
```

Rather you'll need to do the copying of the keys manually, unfortunately if you're using a script like mine (on Fedora 14) when attempting to copy to a host on a non-standard port, such as `-p 2222`.